# Using p5 inside React

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I am trying to integrate a slightly modified version of Boids flocking Sim into my React website. I have tried with both wrapper and p5-React npm's, both work on a smaller scale (i.e. with the examples in the descriptions), but when I try to apply it to the boids sim it just shows "loading...". I have watched the youtube tutorial and fully understand the logic, but I am a bit new to p5. Here is what I am trying to include: https://codepen.io/stephenleemorrow/pen/QWaxKqY

Here is my VS Code:

```
  let flock;
  let img;
  let bg;

  p5.preload = () => {
    img = p5.loadImage("src\pngbyte.com-Open-Window-Window-Png-Image-window-png-images-open-bar.png");
  }

  p5.setup = () => {
    bg = p5.loadImage("src\pixle-cloud-landscape.webp");
    p5.createCanvas(568, 320);
    flock = new Flock();
    // Add an initial set of boids into the system
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      let b = new Boid(p5.width / 2, p5.height / 2);
      flock.addBoid(b);
    }
  }

  p5.draw = (p5) =>  {
    p5.background(51);
    flock.run();
    p5.image(img, -23, -10, 610, 340);
  }

  // Add a new boid into the System
  p5.mouseDragged = () => {
    flock.addBoid(new Boid(p5.mouseX, p5.mouseY));
  }

  // The Nature of Code
  // Daniel Shiffman
  // http://natureofcode.com

  // Flock object
  // Does very little, simply manages the array of all the boids

  function Flock() {
    // An array for all the boids
    this.boids = []; // Initialize the array
  }

  Flock.prototype.run = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.boids.length; i++) {
      this.boids[i].run(this.boids);  // Passing the entire list of boids to each boid individually
    }
  }

  Flock.prototype.addBoid = function (b) {
    this.boids.push(b);
  }

  // The Nature of Code
  // Daniel Shiffman
  // http://natureofcode.com

  // Boid class
  // Methods for Separation, Cohesion, Alignment added

  function Boid(x, y) {
    this.acceleration = p5.createVector(0, 0);
    this.velocity = p5.createVector(p5.random(-1, 1), p5.random(-1, 1));
    this.position = p5.createVector(x, y);
    this.r = 3.0;
    this.maxspeed = 3;    // Maximum speed
    this.maxforce = 0.05; // Maximum steering force
  }

  Boid.prototype.run = function (boids) {
    this.flock(boids);
    this.update();
    this.borders();
    this.render();
  }

  Boid.prototype.applyForce = function (force) {
    // We could add mass here if we want A = F / M
    this.acceleration.add(force);
  }

  // We accumulate a new acceleration each time based on three rules
  Boid.prototype.flock = function (boids) {
    let sep = this.separate(boids);   // Separation
    let ali = this.align(boids);      // Alignment
    let coh = this.cohesion(boids);   // Cohesion
    // Arbitrarily weight these forces
    sep.mult(1.5);
    ali.mult(1.0);
    coh.mult(1.0);
    // Add the force vectors to acceleration
    this.applyForce(sep);
    this.applyForce(ali);
    this.applyForce(coh);
  }

  // Method to update location
  Boid.prototype.update = function () {
    // Update velocity
    this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
    // Limit speed
    this.velocity.limit(this.maxspeed);
    this.position.add(this.velocity);
    // Reset accelertion to 0 each cycle
    this.acceleration.mult(0);
  }

  // A method that calculates and applies a steering force towards a target
  // STEER = DESIRED MINUS VELOCITY
  Boid.prototype.seek = function (target) {
    let desired = p5.Vector.sub(target, this.position);  // A vector pointing from the location to the target
    // Normalize desired and scale to maximum speed
    desired.normalize();
    desired.mult(this.maxspeed);
    // Steering = Desired minus Velocity
    let steer = p5.Vector.sub(desired, this.velocity);
    steer.limit(this.maxforce);  // Limit to maximum steering force
    return steer;
  }

  Boid.prototype.render = function () {
    // Draw a triangle rotated in the direction of velocity
    let theta = this.velocity.heading() + p5.radians(90);
    p5.fill(50);
    p5.stroke(100);
    p5.push();
    p5.translate(this.position.x, this.position.y);
    p5.rotate(theta);
    p5.beginShape();
    p5.vertex(0, -this.r * .5);
    p5.vertex(-this.r, this.r * .5);
    p5.vertex(this.r, this.r * .5);
    p5.endShape(p5.CLOSE);
    p5.pop();
  }

  // Wraparound
  Boid.prototype.borders = function () {
    if (this.position.x < -this.r) this.position.x = p5.width + this.r;
    if (this.position.y < -this.r) this.position.y = p5.height + this.r;
    if (this.position.x > p5.width + this.r) this.position.x = -this.r;
    if (this.position.y > p5.height + this.r) this.position.y = -this.r;
  }

  // Separation
  // Method checks for nearby boids and steers away
  Boid.prototype.separate = function (boids, p5) {
    let desiredseparation = 25.0;
    let steer = p5.createVector(0, 0);
    let count = 0;
    // For every boid in the system, check if it's too close
    for (let i = 0; i < boids.length; i++) {
      let d = p5.Vector.dist(this.position, boids[i].position);
      // If the distance is greater than 0 and less than an arbitrary amount (0 when you are yourself)
      if ((d > 0) && (d < desiredseparation)) {
        // Calculate vector pointing away from neighbor
        let diff = p5.Vector.sub(this.position, boids[i].position);
        diff.normalize();
        diff.div(d);        // Weight by distance
        steer.add(diff);
        count++;            // Keep track of how many
      }
    }
    // Average -- divide by how many
    if (count > 0) {
      steer.div(count);
    }

    // As long as the vector is greater than 0
    if (steer.mag() > 0) {
      // Implement Reynolds: Steering = Desired - Velocity
      steer.normalize();
      steer.mult(this.maxspeed);
      steer.sub(this.velocity);
      steer.limit(this.maxforce);
    }
    return steer;
  }

  // Alignment
  // For every nearby boid in the system, calculate the average velocity
  Boid.prototype.align = function (boids) {
    let neighbordist = 50;
    let sum = p5.createVector(0, 0);
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < boids.length; i++) {
      let d = p5.Vector.dist(this.position, boids[i].position);
      if ((d > 0) && (d < neighbordist)) {
        sum.add(boids[i].velocity);
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
      sum.div(count);
      sum.normalize();
      sum.mult(this.maxspeed);
      let steer = p5.Vector.sub(sum, this.velocity);
      steer.limit(this.maxforce);
      return steer;
    } else {
      return p5.createVector(0, 0);
    }
  }

  // Cohesion
  // For the average location (i.e. center) of all nearby boids, calculate steering vector towards that location
  Boid.prototype.cohesion = function (boids) {
    let neighbordist = 50;
    let sum = p5.createVector(0, 0);   // Start with empty vector to accumulate all locations
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < boids.length; i++) {
      let d = p5.Vector.dist(this.position, boids[i].position);
      if ((d > 0) && (d < neighbordist)) {
        sum.add(boids[i].position); // Add location
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
      sum.div(count);
      return this.seek(sum);  // Steer towards the location
    } else {
      return p5.createVector(0, 0);
    }
  }

}
```

Again, the connection to App() is good cause it works with smaller sketches. I think I'm just missing something in the syntax.
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes and got this running (although with errors in the p5 code that kind of fall out of the scope of the answer).

This might be a typo, but to use this sketch with [ReactP5Wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5-wrapper), you need to export it as a function, so your code above is missing

```
export const sketch = (p5) => {
```

at the start. You actually have the closing bracket at the end, so it's probably a typo in the question.

Later in the code, anywhere you are passing `p5` into a function, like

```
Boid.prototype.separate = function (boids, p5) {
```

you are not passing anything in for `p5` - like

```
let sep = this.separate(boids);
```

so that would cause undefined errors. The `p5` passed into the `sketch` function can be used throughout the sketch so you can remove `p5` from the parameter lists of these other functions.

**The really breaking issue here though was that you were trying to load images from the `/src/` folder.**

Make a directory in the `/public/` folder at the top level of your project, call it `/assets/` and put your images in there.
Then you can reference them like:

```
  p5.preload = () => {
    img = p5.loadImage("assets/test.png");
  }
```

After I do all that, I get the sketch starting, creating the canvas and doing some of the algorithm but it fails at various points that I'm sure will have loads of fun debugging after you get it running to begin with :)

Btw, I'm displaying the sketch in my App component like this, using the ReactP5Wrapper:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactP5Wrapper } from 'react-p5-wrapper';
import { sketch } from './sketch/sketch';

export const App = () => {
   
    return(
        <div>
            <ReactP5Wrapper sketch={sketch}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I fixed the images. About the "p5.", are you saying I should take them out of the individual functions and just use the one fed into sketch? Or am I missing some on certain elements? Would you be able to post or send me your progress?

Comment: Yes, I mean where `p5` is a parameter for any of the functions, take it out of the parameter list so that you are always referencing the one passed in at the beginning of the sketch. After that, there were other bugs but you'd need to try to work through those and ask another question if you run into trouble with something specific. This answer just gets the sketch started and displaying in react.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that I was feeding "p5" into the sketch function, overwriting all of my Vector functions. fed in p, and left p5 on the Vectors and it worked. Though, now my images aren't working. lol. I put them in an Assets in public and used the preload function, but I just get "Loading..." any ideas?

Comment: I'd say to ask a new question if it's only the image loading causing a problem. You could try to create a smaller example that recreates the issue - most likely you'll find your answer yourself by doing that, but otherwise it will be easier to help with.

Comment: My slashes were backward.... that's it. That was all it was... 7 hours...